# Load ByteArray into ImageSource on Android

Tags: nativescript

I have a camera plugin in NativeScript 6.0 that returns a ByteArray under Android when taking a picture. How do I load this into an [ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource)? I cannot load it directly or the app will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load a ByteArray using the [`ImageSource.fromData()`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource#fromdata) method. However, under Android, ImageSource [will only accept an input stream](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/cb58cab213b03137cb28d927b1122d496018d40f/tns-core-modules/image-source/image-source.android.ts#L119):

```
const input = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray);
const imageSource = new ImageSource();
imageSource.fromData(input).then(() => {
  stuff();
});
```